# Folland 2.36 portion of proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left(X,\mathcal{M},\mu\right),\left(Y,\mathcal{N},\nu\right)$ be $\sigma$-finite and $E\subseteq\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}$. Then
$x\mapsto \nu\left(E_x\right),y\mapsto \mu\left(E^y\right)$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable and $\mathcal{N}$-measurable and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu \times \nu(E) &=& \int_X\nu (E_x)d\mu (x)\\
&=& \int_Y\mu(E^y)d\nu (y).
\end{eqnarray*}

In Folland proof goes: Assume that $\mu, \nu$ finite. Let $\mathcal{C}=\{E\subseteq X\times Y: \mathrm{\ all \ conclusions\ hold}\}$. One of the things you have to prove is that $\mathcal{C}\supseteq\{A\times B, A\in \mathcal{M}, B\in \mathcal{N}\}$. Let $A\in \mathcal{M}, B\in \mathcal{N}$ and $E=A\times B\implies E_x =\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            B & \quad x \in A \\
            \emptyset & \quad x\notin A
        \end{array}
    \right. \\
\implies \nu\left(E_x\right)=\nu\left(B\right)\chi_A(x)\implies x\mapsto\nu \left(E_x\right)$

is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable. Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_X \nu \left(E_x\right)d\mu(x) &=& \nu(B)\mu(A)\\
&=&\mu\times\nu(A\times B).
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly, $\mu(E^y)\implies A\times B \in \mathcal{C}$

I'm a little confused why $\nu(E_x)=\nu(B)\chi_A(x)$ implies that the map above is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable. So am I trying to show that for any borel set $S$, $f^{-1}(S)\in \mathcal{M}$ where $f(x)=\nu(E_x)$. If anyone could help me understand this is true it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\chi_A(x)$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable for any $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and since $\nu(B)$ is just a constant for a given $B$, this means the map must be $\mathcal{M}$-measurable as well.

Comment: This is the conclusion I arrived at as well. Thank you!